# How do i get the most sold product for every month there is in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

So I have a database like this:

product_table: (product_id, name),
date_table: (date_id, day, month, year),
sales_table: (sale_id, product_id, date_id, total_value)

I need to get the most sold product for every month that exists in the "date_table" with one query, the only way I was able to do was specifing the month and year in the query, but then i gotta do one query for each month which is not what I need.

Edit:

here is the query i have written:

```
SELECT p.name, d.month, d.year, SUM(s.total_value) as total
FROM sales_table s
INNER JOIN product_table p ON s.product_id = p.product_id
INNER JOIN date_table d ON s.date_id = d.date_id
WHERE d.month = "$month" AND d.year = "$year" 
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

As i said, i have to give the month and the year i want here, but i need the most sold product (with the use of sales value in sales_table not the row count of product table) for every month in just one query!

Comment: You should edit your question and show the query you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` with aggregation.  Assuming that "most sold" refers to the count in the sales table:

```
select sd.*
from (select d.year, d.month, s.product_id, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by d.year, d.month order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from sales s join
           dates d
           on s.date_id = d.date_id
      group by d.year, d.month
     ) sd
where seqnum = 1;
```